# Rails active_resource require JS to do delete by link_to?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

When I use link_to :method=>:delete, what rails has generated is a javascript click, which is not nice if you do come across situation your client just have javascript disabled. That seems a bad idea to me. Any chance to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

What it generates is a form with method="delete", your best bet is to make the form yourself, the only thing is that the submit button won't be a link, but a button.

You should not, by any mean, try to do it with a basic `<a href="">`, because a disruptive action (create, update, delete) should not be made with a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

Your only other option is to do it manually.

Assuming the object you want to delete is in @item, just do this:

```
form_for @item, :method => :delete do |f|
  f.submit "Delete this item"
end
```

Then you can style the submit button to make it look like a normal link, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work without JavaScript use `button_to`:

`<%= button_to 'Delete', @item, :method => :delete %>`

From the doc:

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL
>   created by the set of +options+. This is the safest method to
>   ensure links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by
>   search bots or accelerators.